# Como entrenar un modelo unet basado en resnet con pythorch sin sobrecargar la memoria?

Tags: python, optimización, machine-learning

Estoy intentano crear un modelo UNET usando resnet18 en el encoder, pero al parcer me estoy cargando la RAM. Como entreno esta arquitectura sin cargarme los recursos de la RAM.
NOTA: cuento con 12.68 GB de espacio en RAM, que es lo que otorga colab por default. Me parace que el problema debe estar en la funcion de entrenamiento "fit" pero no lo veo. Estoy entrenando el modelo con 500 pares de imagenes de 1024x1024.

```
 from tqdm import tqdm
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
def fit(model, dataloader, epochs=100, lr=3e-4):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    model.to(device)
    hist = {'loss': [], 'iou': [], 'test_loss': [], 'test_iou': []}
    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
      bar = tqdm(dataloader['train'])
      train_loss, train_iou = [], []
      model.train()
      for imgs, masks in bar:
        imgs, masks = imgs.to(device), masks.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()        
        imgs =torch.tensor(imgs).squeeze(1).permute(0,3,2,1)
        
        y_hat = model(imgs)
        loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        ious = iou(y_hat, masks)
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        train_iou.append(ious)
        bar.set_description(f"loss {np.mean(train_loss):.5f} iou {np.mean(train_iou):.5f}")
      hist['loss'].append(np.mean(train_loss))
      hist['iou'].append(np.mean(train_iou))
      bar = tqdm(dataloader['test'])
      test_loss, test_iou = [], []
      model.eval()
      with torch.no_grad():
        for imgs, masks in bar:
          imgs, masks = imgs.to(device), masks.to(device)
          imgs =torch.tensor(imgs).squeeze(1).permute(0,3,2,1)
          y_hat = model(imgs)
          loss = criterion(y_hat, masks)
          ious = iou(y_hat, masks)
          test_loss.append(loss.item())
          test_iou.append(ious)
          bar.set_description(f"test_loss {np.mean(test_loss):.5f} test_iou {np.mean(test_iou):.5f}")
      hist['test_loss'].append(np.mean(test_loss))
      hist['test_iou'].append(np.mean(test_iou))
      print(f"\nEpoch {epoch}/{epochs} loss {np.mean(train_loss):.5f} iou {np.mean(train_iou):.5f} test_loss {np.mean(test_loss):.5f} test_iou {np.mean(test_iou):.5f}")
    return hist

model = UNetResnet()
hist = fit(model, dataloader, epochs=1)
```